# Need suggestion on strategy to handle informatica error "value larger than specified precision allowed this column" as it is causing repeated failures

Tags: business-intelligence, informatica, informatica-powercenter, obiee

We are facing Informatica ERROR "ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column" again and again due to incorrect value entered by user in source system (Oracle EBS).

What strategy we follow currently is:

1. Informatica ETL fails due to this error
2. We request user to correct the value in source system
3. Informatica ETL fails until the value is corrected in source
4. After value correction, ETL completed successfully.

But we need a strategy to handle this kind of incorrect values which are causing repetative failure to whole execution plan.

Note: Issue is not with floating number.

For example: If there is column unit price having precision Number(8,2), users are putting larger values by mistake such as 123456789123.00 , 9876541236487.00 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't a problem with a pure, technical solution, but a question about data quality and data handling.

If the users are "putting larger values by mistake" then why doesn't the source system prevent this at data entry? Why correct a mistake that should never exist in the first place?

If you "need a strategy" as you claim: Do things right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The field size of your source should match what is set for the field size on the source system then whether the user entered a wrong value or not it will go through your mapping. You shouldnt have a more restrictive source than allowed on the source system (although it probably boils down to one party not fulfilling the interface agreement between your teams and that party changes their code)